# What is the difference between a CA certificate and the certificate that we can download from the padlock?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I am very new to this, so please cooperate with my lack of knowledge.
I have to establish a secure connection with an organization.So,
I issued a CSR to that organization.
From that I came to know that my CSR had my public key, which I then send to the organization.
The organization verified my organization and in return provided me with a .crt file.
The .crt file had the same public key.
So I believe my CSR was resent back to me but with a trust and a CA approval.
So now my question is, where do I find the public key of the organization and also I followed these steps.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore <cacerts path> -storepass <password> -alias myorgdomain -import -file <crt path>
```

where in the crt path I provided the path to the .crt file which the other organization provided me with.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out <filename> -inkey <private key> -in <crt file> -password pass:changeit
```

then I converted the file to pfx and then the file to jks.
In place of  I kept the private which was generated during CSR generation. And in  I kept the path to the .crt file provided by the organization.

This seems to work though. But I don't have a clear understanding how?

I want to know how this is working and also where do I find the public key of that organization?

Comment: The CA, might have sent you its public key that signed your public key  that you sent in the CSR, if not you need to ask for it

Comment: @Pras I was just provided with a .crt file . But the application does work but I wan't to know how?

Comment: The public key of the CA is in its certificate, which is in the certificate chain it sent you in response to your CSR.

Comment: @Pras Digital signature are signed wth private keys, not public keys.

Comment: @user207421 Yes I should have mentioned it specifically..

Comment: @user207421 thank you for clarification. But my question still has not been answered. I studied in many sites that just like you said , a chain of certificates are sent by the CA (bundle). But, I receiver just a single .crt file. Please clear my doubts in an answer.

Comment: Then you needs to ask for the rest of the chain. But possibly you already received the entire chain in a single file.

Comment: @user207421 is there any possible way to know that?

Comment: If it works there must be a chain. What is your actual problem?